# Sorting received data from query

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet where in sheet B C D E  data gets entered and exported to sheet E via a query.

But it sorts it per sheet and not mix them in order.

I don't want a date order of sheet B then sheet C.

I need it that 1-1-23 on sheet D is in front of 31-12-2022 from sheet B

This is the query formula I use now

```
=QUERY({SheetB!A2:N;SheetC!A2:N;SheetD!A4:N;SheetE!A5:N},"select * where Col1 is not null",0)
```

`Col1` is the column with the dates in it which need to be sorted.

I tried sorting via the Sort A-Z method that is not working I also tried to add Sorty By Col1 as shown below

```
=QUERY({SheetB!A2:N;SheetC!A2:N;SheetD!A4:N;SheetE!A5:N},"select * where Col1 is not null",0,Sorty By Col1)
```

Example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gQUkJUW8ChWj59vtDu64rI1ozZjY6b5ABmzns6lgF9o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

`=QUERY({SheetB!A2:N;SheetC!A2:N;SheetD!A4:N;SheetE!A5:N},"select * where Col1 is not null ORDER BY Col1 DESC",0)`

Comment: Thanks Rockin!  it gave me the last step I needed   I used your formula and chances DESC to Asc and it worked!